# Wrap text around symbol

Tags: lettrine, wrap, drop-cap

How is it possible to wrap text around a symbol? This is my code so far:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2][\danger]{%
    \colorbox{lime}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
        {\Huge#1}{#2}%
    }}%
}
\begin{document}
\mybox{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want lettrine? See http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/lettrine.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `lettrine` package for this, which is usually used for having a large first letter that spans several lines. It needs a bit of adjustment because of the symbol's large depth:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2][\danger]{%
    \colorbox{lime}{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
        \lettrine[lraise=.2,findent=1pt,nindent=0pt]{#1}{}{#2} }%
    }%
}
\begin{document}

\mybox{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The optional argument for the `\mybox` environment makes no sense if you don't use it.

Comment: @Thorsten: Thanks for the note. I've edited my answer to incorporate the optional argument in the way the Duwee intended.

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, I think it is difficult to do this in LaTeX. There is a [`shapepar`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/shapepar.html) package, which can dig a hole in the text and put something in the hole. But it's not easy to customize the shape of the hole to fit specific symbol.

An example of predefined circle hole:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shapepar}

\begin{document}

\cutout{r}(-4em,5\baselineskip)\shapepar{\circleshape}
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut
cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut cut\par
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\end{document}
```

This kind of work is easier in ConTeXt, with help of MetaFun. You may refer:

http://mirror.contextgarden.net/general/manuals/metafun-s.pdf

---

If you just want a rectangle hole, you can use (old) [`picinpar`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/picinpar.html), (newer) [`picins`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/picins.html) and [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/wrapfig.html) for this.

For more simpler situations, `lettrine` package is enough. Also there are `\hangindent`, `\hangafter` commands to get a paragraph of special shape.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`wrapfig`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package for this:

> ```
>  Environments "wrapfigure" and "wraptable" place a figure or table
>  at the side of the page and wrap text around it.
>
>  \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{r}[34pt]{5cm} <figure> \end{wrapfigure}
>                     --  -  ----  ---
>  [number of narrow lines] {placement} [overhang] {width of figure}%
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> Environments similar to "wrapfigure" and "wraptable" may be easily added,
> or invoked by "\begin{wrapfloat}{float_name}"
> ```