# How can include wrap text around profile picture as biography without using "\documentclass{ieeeaccess}"

Tags: two-column, templates, wrapfigure, overleaf, biography

I'm working on an expose (research proposal) and I selected this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/uncg-phy-419-f19-proposal-template/mkzbzxjzysty) in overleaf which is 2 columns. now the problem is I want to include a short biography of 2 persons in the end without in form of text-wrap without using `\begin{IEEEbiography} \end{IEEEbiography}` since it messes up the designed template. Actually, in this template, they didn't use `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}` without `cls` file.
Considering I checked related [post1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291/how-to-wrap-text-around-a-figure), [post2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10906/wrap-text-around-symbol), so far I tried 2 methods as follows unsuccessfully after I had included `\usepackage{wrapfig} \usepackage{lipsum}`:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% enables hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction \& Background}

\section{References}
\bibliography{bibfile}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

%Method 1
\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{L}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{a1.png}
%blablabla
\end{wrapfigure}

%\lipsum[2-3]


%Method 2
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
  %\begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.18\textwidth]{a1.png}
%blablabla
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

So far the output is as follows:
[image: img]

Any helps to improve this template will be appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  You images do not look anything like your code fragment.  If I were trying to produce something like the mage, I would use \noindent\rlap and \raisebox for the photo and \hangindent for the text.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sir if you check that template I addressed you see how it looks like but I just updated the post. Would you offer a complete script to make it correct? As you see it doesn't work!

Comment: Your sample document has no text after the wrapfigures, so the pictures are dumped without wrapping any text. Your widths specification "0.5\textwidth" is wrong -- it is wider than a whole column width!

Comment: @DonaldArseneau Thanks for your input since you're so into it, may I ask you to check this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557107/how-can-i-include-small-line-before-or-above-title-in-2-columns-document-in-cent) regarding generating short line in the center above title in 2 columns format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This overlaps 8 lines of text with the image with a width of 1in and a gap of 1em.  Not sure how to force two columns side by side with revtex4-2.  IIRC, IEEE uses a tabular in the title area of \twocolumn.

BTW, \lipsum has gotten more difficult to use lately.

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
%superscriptaddress,
%groupedaddress,
%unsortedaddress,
%runinaddress,
%frontmatterverbose, 
%preprint,
%preprintnumbers,
%nofootinbib,
%nobibnotes,
%bibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
%pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}% enables hyperlinks in the PDF
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction \& Background}

\section{References}
\bibliography{bibfile}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.

%Method 1
\lipsum[1]
\medskip

\hangindent=\dimexpr 1in+1em\relax
\hangafter=-8
\noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in]{example-image}}%
  \hspace{1em}}
\indent\LipsumPar{2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input it works but despite I used `\clearpage` Overleaf includes some unknown words which I didn't mention in the biography profile and fills automatically which I highlighted with red color. Do you know how I can avoid it? See the [picture](https://i.imgur.com/GE9CERg.png), please.

Comment: They are from \lipsum and \LipsumPar to add fake text to MSEs.  Otherwise, they serve no useful purpose.  Just get rid of them and the package.

Answer (score 0):

```
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\hangindent=\dimexpr 1in+1em\relax
\hangafter=-8
\noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.29in]{author2.jpg}}%
    \hspace{1em}}
\textbf{SECOND AUTHOR NAME} has done her bachelor's degree from ABC institution in 2000. She has done her master's degree from XYZ institution in 2010. She has completed her PhD degree in ABC from the Institute of EFG in 2020.
\\ \indent
Second paragraph shows her research experience, publications, awards etc.Second paragraph shows her research experience, publications, awards etc.Second paragraph shows her research experience, publications, awards etc.Second paragraph shows her research experience, publications, awards etc.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please do not post only code, explain it in your own words too!